# Error while installing Microsfts webdriver for use with python module selenium

Tags: python, windows, selenium

Following the instructions from this link in my effort to use Python's selenium module with MS Edge: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

I get:

```
C:\Windows\system32>DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17134.1

Image Version: 10.0.17134.407


Error: 87

A Windows capability name was not recognized.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

I'm a little lost with regards to where to go from here.

The entirety of the log contents put me over the character limit so here are some final lines:

```
CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Disconnecting Provider: AppxManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Finalizing the servicing provider(ProvManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Disconnecting Provider: ProvManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Finalizing the servicing provider(AssocManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Disconnecting Provider: AssocManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Finalizing the servicing provider(GenericManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Disconnecting Provider: GenericManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Finalizing the servicing provider(OfflineSetupManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Disconnecting Provider: OfflineSetupManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Finalizing the servicing provider(SysprepManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Disconnecting Provider: SysprepManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Finalizing the servicing provider(Edition Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Disconnecting Provider: Edition Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Finalizing the servicing provider(SetupPlatformManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Disconnecting Provider: SetupPlatformManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Releasing the local reference to OSServices. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Disconnecting Provider: OSServices - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=13388 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=16172 TID=14536 Closing session event handle 0x1a4 - CDISMManager::CleanupImageSessionEntry
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=16172 TID=14536 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=16172 TID=14536 Disconnecting Provider: FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2018-11-22 13:39:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=16172 TID=14536 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
```

Comment: all those are Info statements in log. Are there any Warning or Error statements?

Comment: also make sure you started CMD with "Run as Administrator"